# How can I change the order of address field columns on screens and reports?

Tags: localisation, addresses

In Europe, the postcode mostly precedes the town name. I could not find any options for changing the order of the columns for these fields, particularly on the constituent report.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried making adjustments under **Administer > Localisation > Address Settings**?

[image: Address Formats]

Comment: Unfortunately this mechanism allows the layout of labels and displays to be changed, but importantly NOT the ordering of columns in the report: there it is only possible to choose fields, but not to specify their ordering

Comment: I see -- it wasn't clear to me what you meant. I've updated the question to try to clarify where you need to rearrange things.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are 2 routes:

1. you switch on the address parsing setting that splits the address line into street_name, number and unit. You then have to develop an extension that builds the street_address into the sequence you want (which is then used throughout the system). We have done this for some Dutch installations, check https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.streetformatnl
2. leave CiviCRM to do what it does but customize the report where you need it to be in a different sequence.

Comment: It isn't necessary to parse the address in order to reverse the order of the City and Postal Code fields. Though perhaps @David Christie wants to change more than that.

Comment: Actually I just want to use the typical continental European ordering (and not the typical US or UK one!)

Comment: I've discovered in the meanwhile that one can override the PHP code that is used to build up the data, but it was not so easy to understand how to refer to particular fields in the database. This way, it was possible to swap two fields around relatively easily. Needs programming skills, though

Answer (score 1):

To modify the column order in the Constituent Report you will need to do some development (you can hire a CiviCRM partner to make these sorts of minor modifications for you).

The developer might want to override the function select() and move the fields around as desired, since these are later used to build an array in the same order.

Comment: I need this feature, it's kind of insane that we can't have the UI re-arrange the order of the fields in the report? Maybe I'm just entitled.