# How do I change the order of fields in the pay later invoice information?

Tags: forms, paylater

This is similar to [How can I change the order of address field columns on screens and reports?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/how-can-i-change-the-order-of-address-field-columns-on-screens-and-reports), but relates to the order the fields are show when "pay later" information is requested.

I would like to move the "Postnummer" (post code) to before the "Postadress" (City), because that's the way we do it in many European countries ;-)

[image]

And I would like to avoid hacks like the one suggested in [How to change order in billing address](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30842/how-to-change-order-in-billing-address).

Answer (score 0):

> the order the fields are show when "pay later" information is requested

not sure i am answering your question - but this sounds like it is just a Profile and you could look for this in Administer > Custom > Profiles, and then tweak the order there

Comment: It's not a profile, sadly (https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2761). I wish it was. But you already knew that from https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42202/how-can-i-add-company-to-billing-pay-later-fields ;-)

Comment: i concur i have not answered the question so will remove - perhaps you can answer it yourself and point to that lab issue.